# Android align textview and edittext

Tags: android, android-layout

In the following xml file.i am trying to align the contents.i.e, first textview followed by the edittext and so on in the next line.But tight now the text is imposed one on another how to resolve this issue.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >


      <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="0.70" >



          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/hostname"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/ip"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:text="hostname" />


          <EditText
              android:id="@+id/ip"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
              android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
              android:ems="10"
              android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >

          </EditText>


   <TextView
              android:id="@+id/username"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/ip"
              android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ip"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:text="Hostname" />
          <EditText
              android:id="@+id/username"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
              android:layout_below="@+id/ip"
              android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
              android:ems="10" />

           <TextView
              android:id="@+id/password"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/hostname"
              android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/username"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:text="Password" />
          <EditText
              android:id="@+id/password"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_below="@+id/password"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
              android:ems="10"
              android:inputType="textPassword" />


      </RelativeLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Dude.. Instead of RelativeLayout use TableLayout... and put TextView and EditText pair in each row.. Simple..:-)

Comment: Your trying to show text on the edit text right?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The Best way is remove all the textview and set `andoid:hint` to edit text .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="HostName"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="HostName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  What if one wants to show pre-filled data in some of the EditTexts?  The hint would not be useful to describe what the user is seeing in that case.

Answer (score 11):

Another way to do it, that worked well for me, is, in your xml file, to add a parent `<LinearLayout>` that specifies `android:orientation="horizontal"` to encompass your `TextView` and `EditText`.

This parent `LinearLayout` has to be **inside** your very first `LinearLayout` that has to specify a `android:orientation="vertical"` :

```
<!-- Root Layout -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" <!-- Vertical orientation -->
    android:paddingLeft="15sp"
    android:paddingRight="15sp"
    android:paddingTop="15sp"
    android:paddingBottom="15sp" >


    <!-- First Row -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" <!-- Horizontal orientation for the row -->
        android:paddingTop="15sp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Poids :"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/btn_poids"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:hint="Entrez votre poids"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <!-- Second Row -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" <!-- Horizontal orientation for the row -->
        android:paddingTop="15sp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Taille :"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/btn_poids"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:hint="Entrez votre taille"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the result (the warning signs are because of the hardcoded strings for the hints and text...) :

[image: Result of the above]

Comment: The above code is good if `TextView`'s  length are equal, if not they won't be vertically aligned

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue trying to target android 4.X. I solved it by using `android:gravity="center_vertical"`

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/itemNameLabel"
            android:text="@string/entry_item_label"
            android:textSize="@dimen/baseTextSize"
            android:layout_weight=".15"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".85"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/itemName"
            android:textSize="@dimen/baseTextSize"
            android:hint="Food, Video Game, etc..." />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Got the hint to handle my own case here

Answer (score 1):

Your using the same id for multiple views, and then multiple views are using `layout_below` using the same id, that's why there are some that are on top of each other. Make them unique ids. Also the id you are using for some `align_left` arnt even there, like `editText1` for example.

Short answer: use unique ids for each view and check what your referencing for alignments and positioning etc.

Your next problem is that you shouldn't try and layer your views like this, there is something called `android:hint="hint text"` this is what I think you want. The text will hide once the user starts to input text, but other then that its like there is a text view on top of it...

Answer (score 0):

None of these solved my problem. What I do is I add 
`android:textAlignment="center"` to the textView in XML. the edit text is centered by default.

Both the `TextView` and the `EditText` are in a horizontal `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score -1):

Add this attribute to EditText:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/hostname"
```